# RailsCast calendar code not printing in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

[RailsCast #213 Calendars (revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars-revised?view=asciicast) is about making a calendar that shows the `published_on` date for blog posts. In `views/articles/index.html`, the author puts this code:

```erb
<%= calendar @date do |date| %>
  <%= date.day %>  
<% end %>
```

That calls a helper method he includes in `calendar_helper.rb`. This works on a Rails 3.2 app, but when I try to use it in a Rails 4 app, I only get a blank page. I put `puts` statements in the `table` method:

```rb
def table
  content_tag :table, class: "calendar" do
    puts header
    puts week_rows
    header + week_rows
  end
end
```

and the calendar printed to the server log, but still nothing is showing on the page. Is there something about this code that makes it obsolete in Rails 4 with Ruby 2?

```rb
module CalendarHelper
  def calendar(date = Date.today, &block)
    Calendar.new(self, date, block).table
  end

  class Calendar < Struct.new(:view, :date, :callback)
    HEADER = %w[Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday]
    START_DAY = :sunday

    delegate :content_tag, to: :view

    def table
      content_tag :table, class: "calendar" do
        header + week_rows
      end
    end

    def header
      content_tag :tr do
        HEADER.map { |day| content_tag :th, day }.join.html_safe
      end
    end

    def week_rows
      weeks.map do |week|
        content_tag :tr do
          week.map { |day| day_cell(day) }.join.html_safe
        end
      end.join.html_safe
    end

    def day_cell(day)
      content_tag :td, view.capture(day, &callback), class: day_classes(day)
    end

    def day_classes(day)
      classes = []
      classes << "today" if day == Date.today
      classes << "notmonth" if day.month != date.month
      classes.empty? ? nil : classes.join(" ")
    end

    def weeks
      first = date.beginning_of_month.beginning_of_week(START_DAY)
      last = date.end_of_month.end_of_week(START_DAY)
      (first..last).to_a.in_groups_of(7)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found in the [RailsDispatch Blog Post](http://www.railsdispatch.com/posts/upgrading-a-rails-2-app-to-rails-3) about upgrading from Rails 2 to Rails 3 the reason (search for the section "Block Helpers").

> Rails 2.3, block helpers, such as form_for worked by using <% %>. This was a bit confusing, because they emitted content to the page, so you’d expect them to use <%= %>.
>
> ... In Rails 3, you use <%= %> for block helpers, which vastly simplifies the process of building block helpers yourself.
>
> ... Rails 3.0 will continue to work with the old syntax, but it emits deprecation warnings, and the core team will remove the old syntax in Rails 3.1.

So if was a flaw in Rails 2.3, which was addressed in Rails 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the code wrong. It works if the first line includes the equal sign `<%=` which kind of surprises me as being necessary.

```
<%= calendar @date do |date| %>
  <%= date.day %>  
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes it's strange and a little confusing. (Almost sure that) earlier version of ruby did not used <%= for forms, but now it is required. The RailCast is probably a little outdated and old so that's why he used <% instead.